# How to sample from a given accessible PDF?

Tags: sampling, markov-chain-montecarlo, gaussian-mixture-distribution, gibbs

I am learning Gibbs Sampling for GMMs. Particularly, given $\boldsymbol \theta$, I must sample from the latent $\boldsymbol z$ before sampling $\boldsymbol x$.

The PDF of $\boldsymbol z$ is given as$$
P(z=k|\boldsymbol x,\boldsymbol\theta)\propto P(z=k)\mathcal N(\mu_k,\Sigma_k)
$$ for $k=1\cdots.K$ and by assumption, $\mu,\Sigma,P(z_k)$ are given.

Gibb's sampling states that I should iteratively sample from $\boldsymbol z$ and $\boldsymbol x$ and accept all sample (since it is a MH with proposal probability $1$).

The problem is, how do I sample from $\boldsymbol z$? Sampling from $P(\boldsymbol x|\boldsymbol\theta)$ is easy once I have $\boldsymbol z$ since I will simply select a Gaussian component corresponding to $z_k$ and call packages for sampling a Gaussian distribution.

Do I need to perform another MCMC for a every single sample of $z$ or perhaps rejection or importance sampling?

Comment: What is $\pi_k$?

Comment: @Tim it is $P(z_i=k)$

Comment: Are you sure you didn't forget about $\sum_k$ there?

Comment: @Tim there is no summation over $k$ in the numerator, but I omitted the normalization constant in the denominator which is $\sum_k \pi_k\mathcal N(\mu_k|\Sigma_k)$

Comment: @Tim I also realized that but sampling from the $P(z=k|\theta)$ before sampling $x$ is the recipe for Gibbs sampling of GMMs as indicated in Probabilistic Machine Learning: Advance Topics, Murphy 2023

Comment: Gibbs means sampling $\theta$ given $(x,z)$ and $z$ given $(\theta,x)$.

Comment: Sampling from $z$ given $(\theta,x)$ means picking one out of $K$ values with known probabilities, in other words, sampling from a Multinomial distribution. Generating a single Uniform and comparing it to the CDF of the Multinomial is straightforward.

Comment: @Xi'an I missed that $P(z=k|\theta)$ are literally discrete probs that can be sampled from sampling a Multinomial distribution by plugging in the solved probs. However, I am confused by your comment "**sampling $z$ given $(\theta,x)$**", I have seen that $z$ is conditioned with $\theta$ not $x$, and rather, $x$ is sampled given $z$ as $x|z$

Comment: In usual notations, $x$ is the data [known since observed] and $\theta$ is the parameter [unknown hence to be simulated].

Comment: Ok thank you! Your comment completely solved my problem.